# Creating new Collection in view - Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I'm writing a simple Backbone.js code, that create exercise based on config fetched from JSON.

The flow is now:

1. Some kind of controller in my code get JSON file (by jQuery).
2. I create description model (based on part of my JSON file), and an answer collections by iterating through all items in 'answers' array in JSON file, and adding them to collection.
3. I create views, based on model & collection.

All of this was described and resolved in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420741/backbone-and-best-practice-getting-config-json)

That's part of my JSON file which is configuration for an exercise.

```
"config": {
    "id": "myWomiExercise1",
    "type": "",
    "numberOfSets": 0,
    "numberOfPresentedAnswers": 3,
    "numberOfCorrectAnswerInSet": 1,
    "randomAnswers": true,
    "exerciseTrueFalseType": false
},
```

That means, that I can have for example 30 answers in my JSON, and there will be randomly selected (by using underscore methods, probably), to show 3 (which one is correct).

I pass configuration to new View, and have access to It by adding to the view

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
}
```

And than, I need to create, as my config says ("randomAnswers": true) new set of answers.
As google said me, I probably need to create a new collection using underscore methods, by combining few of them - because what I need is, set created that will have *x* answers presented, from which *y* will be correct, and *x-y* incorrect, and finnaly, randomized.
As chaining doesn't work with 'where', I'm wondering what is the best way of doing this? My idea, which looks pretty poor is having this in View:

```
randomAnswerSet: function(config) {
    var correct = config.numberOfCorrectAnswerInSet;
    var wrong = config.numberOfPresentedAnswers - correct;
    var set = [];
    set.push(
        _.sample( this.collection.getCorrect(), correct )
    );
    set.push(
        _.sample( this.collection.getWrong(), wrong )
    );

    this.collection = new  AnswersCollection(_.shuffle(_.flatten(set)));
},
```

And another question, should I create a new collection, like this randomAnswerSet in View and than render this view normally? Or there are better ways of doing this?

It confuses me, because I need a control button 'new example', which will recreate collection (as everything is randomized, It should gives completly new set), but do I need to destroy old one? There will be a lot of collection when user will click a button 10 times, is it optimal?

Thanks guys for all and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do realize that if the user clicks "new example" he will immediately know the correct answer, right? It will be the only one that gets displayed twice...

As to how to implement it, I would define a new collection type which holds all the answers, and returns a set with a method. You can see a similar implementation here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/entities/common.js (see the FilteredCollection), which is used in https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js

The way it is used in the application is that the filtered collection hold a reference to the original collection of contacts (all the data), and returns a new collection when it gets filtered. In your case, you simply have a `randomAnswerSet` function that return a group of answers instead of the `filter`method in the files above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The user sees a first group of possible answers : AXB (with X being the correct answer). He clicks to get a new example and sees XCD. Since X is displayed each time and there can only be one correct answer, he knows that X is the answer.

Comment: Yeap, but there can be multiple correct answers, as getCorrect() returns array of all answers that 'correct' is true in the collection, am I right?:) 
By the way, thanks for your answer, I'll test this in a second :)

Comment: ok, you are right, the problem is it mainly all the time returns the same objects, in different order, I don't know why… Something in this randomAnswerSet must be wrong. Have you got any idea how to get it the best way?